# Python - "object layout"

Tags: python, class-design

can somebody describe the following exception? What is the "object layout" and how it is defined? Thanks

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_gui.py", line 5, in <module>
    suite = AlgorithmEngine('gui_suite')
  File "/home/honza/Research/Voiar/algorithm.py", line 169, in __init__
    self.algorithms = self._initAlgorithms()
  File "/home/honza/Research/Voiar/algorithm.py", line 232, in _initAlgorithms
    self._initGUIAlgorithm(obj)
  File "/home/honza/Research/Voiar/algorithm.py", line 218, in _initGUIAlgorithm
    cls.__bases__ = bases
TypeError: __bases__ assignment: 'QWidget' object layout differs from 'GUIAlgorithm'
```

Comment: Possibly related: [autoreload gratuitous "object layout differs" error](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/13347)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that you tried to change the type of an object (by assigning to `__bases__`) and the new type wasn't compatible with the old one. This happens when the underlying C data structure isn't the same for both types.

See http://www.mail-archive.com/python-list@python.org/msg52950.html for a list of differences between types that might trigger this exception.

Comment: It is slightly disappointing how many caveats in general one runs into when going into the (exposed) internals of Python--the consistency and cleanness of Python just breaks down there.  This here is just one example.

Comment: @ErikKaplun replacing `__bases__` on the fly is hackery and cannot therefore  contribute to the overall impression of a language :)

Comment: Gonna add going from a pure Python class at the start to adding in `collections.abc.Mapping` in the hierarchy to assist with making my original `__class__` behave more like a dict.  Assigning to `self.__class__` (again a pure Python class) then give this exact error.  Take away subclassing `collections.abc.Mapping` and error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error occurred when I tried to use change the `__class__` of an object that also has `__slots__`, like this:

```py
class Base:
    __slots__ = ('a', 'b', 'c')

class Child(Base):
    pass


obj = Base()
obj.__class__ = Child  
# -> TypeError: __class__ assignment: 'Child' object layout differs from 'Base'
```

Comment: Child should have `__slots__ = tuple()`